# mysql - How do I display all of the biggest values, if there are multiple entries in the table with the same value?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to display the names of students who are enrolled in the longest courses. To give some context, when the command:

```
SELECT s.student_name, c.duration 
FROM course_table c 
JOIN student_table s 
ON s.course_id = c.course_id;
```

is ran, it will display:

```
+---------------+----------+
| student_name  | duration |
+---------------+----------+
| John Smith    |        4 |
| Alan O'Brien  |        4 |
| Sarah Murphy  |        3 |
| Sean Mulligan |        4 |
+---------------+----------+
```

I have used:

```
SELECT s.student_name, MAX(c.duration) 
FROM course_table c 
JOIN student_table s 
ON s.course_id = c.course_id;
```

but this only displays one of the students doing a 4 year course. I have also tried using 'limit 3' but not only does that not work, that would feel like a band-aid fix. Is there any other function in MySQL that is similar to 'MAX()' but will display all of the largest values, assuming there's more than one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Get the overall Max duration value out of all the **assigned** courses (assigned to a student) in a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html).
- Join this derived table to the main tables using `duration`.

Try the following:

```
SELECT s.student_name,
       c.duration
FROM   course_table c
       JOIN student_table s
         ON s.course_id = c.course_id
       JOIN (SELECT Max(c2.duration) AS max_duration
             FROM   course_table c2
                    JOIN student_table s2
                      ON s2.course_id = c2.course_id) AS dt
         ON dt.max_duration = c.duration
```

Comment: I don't understand why the student table is included in the subquery

Comment: @Strawberry Because there can be a course which has the maximum duration, but it is **not assigned** to any of the students